# If L is a non-regular language over {a}, are all Myhill-Nerode classes singletons?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Is there a non-regular language over unary alphabet $\{a\}$ which has a Myhill-Nerode equivalence class that is not a singleton?

Comment: Can you please incorporate all relevant constraints into the body of the question?  (not just the title)  In particular the focus on a unary alphabet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you are talking about Myhill-Nerode classes.

We can view $L$ as a subset of $\mathbb N$, since only the length of the word is important on $\{a\}$. Moreover two numbers $i,j$ are equivalent iff for any $n$, $i+n\in L$ iff $j+n\in L$.
Assume there are $i<j$ equivalent, and let $k=j-i$. Then for any $n$, we have $n\in L$ iff $n \bmod k\in L$, since you can replace $j$ by $i$ as many times as you want. This means $L$ is regular, because it depends only of the congruence classes modulo $k$.

So the answer to your question is Yes: if $L$ is nonregular, all classes are singletons.

Comment: Wait, this isn't true, right? Consider $L = RS$ where $R = \{a, b\}$ and $S = \{ww^R \mid w \in \{a, b\}^*\}$. The strings $a$ and $b$ are equivalent with respect to the indistinguishability relation used by Myhill-Nerode; $L$ is a non-regular language and at least one equivalence class contains two things. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Patrick87 This is only true for languages over a unary alphabet! In general it's definitely not true.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ah, good catch. I didn't pay enough attention to the title and focused on the question body, which isn't specific to unary languages. Should really pay more attention.

Comment: Your general argument is correct, but I guess you made a mistake in the details or I did not understand your argument. As the right congruence just holds for adding words, but not "removing" them (and not $0^i \equiv_L \lambda$), we just have for $m > i$ that $m$ is equivalent to $i + (m-i)~\mbox{mod}~k$ or $0^m \equiv_L 0^{i + ((m-i)~\mbox{mod}~k}$, so each such element falls in one of the classes $[0^i], [0^{i+1}], \ldots, [0^{i+(k-1)}]$ and the elements $0^0, 0^1, \ldots, 0^{i-1}$ do not have to fall into of those classes. Nevertheless the same conclusion is reached.

Comment: @Stefan No I think it's correct: if $a^3$ is equivalent to $a^5$, it means you can replace $a^5$ by $a^3$ in any context, so even removing two $a$'s is ok, and you get $a\equiv a^3$ for instance.

Comment: I am not sure, consider $L = (aa)^{\ast} \cup \{a\}$, then $a \not\equiv a^3$ but $a^3 \equiv a^5$, more precisely we have $[\varepsilon]=\{\varepsilon\}, [a] = \{a\}, [aa]=(aa)^{+}$ and $[aaa] = a(aa)^{+}$.

Comment: @Stefan : you're right, in my example you can remove two $a$ as soon as there are at least $5$, I went too fast in my answer. So the equivalence classes are still finite, but before $j$ they can be arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, does not change the conclusion; in your example each element $a^k$ with $k \ge 5$ falls either into $[aaa]$ or $[aaaa]$, and beside this we might have distinct classes $[\varepsilon]$, $[a]$, $[aa]$.